# Sabre SOAP CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ NEED 5 error

Tags: sabre

I am trying to use the Sabre CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ SOAP request to create an PNR.

It is an Orchestrated APIs which combines EnhancedAirBookRQ and PassengerDetailsRQ

I keep running into error 
EndTransactionLLSRQ: NEED 5.

I couldn't find information anywhere on what this error message means.

Any advise greatly appreciated.

Reponse

```
<ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="NotProcessed">
   <Error type="Application" timeStamp="2018-08-06T12:15:24.587-05:00">
      <SystemSpecificResults>
         <Message code="ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR">PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details</Message>
      </SystemSpecificResults>
   </Error>
   <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-08-06T12:15:23.989-05:00">
      <SystemSpecificResults>
         <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">EndTransactionLLSRQ: NEED 5.</Message>
      </SystemSpecificResults>
   </Warning>
   <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-08-06T12:15:24.034-05:00">
      <SystemSpecificResults>
         <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">EndTransactionLLSRQ: NEED 5.</Message>
      </SystemSpecificResults>
   </Warning>
</ApplicationResults>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the TJR requirement of a 5. remark in the PNR.

Option 1: Add a 5. remark. You can ask the agency if they require a specific remark (as they do have the setting active to require the remark), and put that remark in. Otherwise just add any 5. remark to the PNR.

Option 2: Turn off the 5. requirement.
To do this you will need a Sabre terminal with SI9 access. Log into the PCC and do SI9 then W/KINR¥OFF

Hope this helps

Comment: 5. remark btw is located in the  <Remark Type="General">                         <Text>XXX</Text></Remark> node